# HTML label before input CSS hover states

Tags: html, css, input, label

I have a form where I placed my labels before inputs like this:

```
<label for="email">Confirm Email</label>
<input type="text" id="email" />
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" />
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" />
<label for="company">Company</label>
<input type="text" id="company" />
```

When I try to use the CSS to style the label, when I hover the inputs like this (`input:hover + label`), the CSS applies on the next label instead on the one that has the `for=` property. For example, if I try to hover the email input, it will apply the `input:hover+label` effect on the 2nd label with `for="firstname"`.

My design structure has labels on top and inputs under them, so I can't switch their position.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting a label placed before an input in various states](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647427/selecting-a-label-placed-before-an-input-in-various-states)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some clever CSS you can have the label after the input, but still have the label look like it's on top of the input http://jsfiddle.net/8YqN2/2/

```
<input type="text" id="email" />
<label for="email">Confirm Email</label>    
<input type="text" id="firstname" />
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>    
<input type="text" id="lastname" />
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>    
<input type="text" id="company" /> 
<label for="company">Company</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input:hover + label  {
  background-color: #eee;
}

input {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -2.5em;
}
```

<strike>I don't think this is possible with CSS alone</strike>, if you can live with the effect for users with JS enabled, you can use the following. http://jsfiddle.net/8YqN2/1/

```
$('input').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).prev().addClass('hover');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).prev().removeClass('hover');
  }
);

label.hover  {
  background-color: #eee;
} ​
```

​

Comment: this is exactly what i've done and it looks OK :) Thank you very much, Juan Mendes!

Comment: This is a pretty ghetto solution. A better solution in modern times would be to use flexbox

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thanks for your comment but you do realize this was written in 2012, and that flex-boxes aren't well supported even in 2016?

Comment: Absolutely. That is why I commented - to point readers to better alternatives

Comment: Also, if you read the restrictions from the OP about reworking the HTML, it doesn't sound like they would be able to rework the HTML to use flex-boxes

Comment: Sure there is. Take a look at [the recent duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647427/selecting-a-label-placed-before-an-input-in-various-states)

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. The "+" sign is an "[adjacent sibling selector](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200510/css_21_selectors_part_2/)".

> The selector matches an element which is the next sibling to the first element.

In your case, the selector matches the `label` element which is the next sibling to `input:hover`.

CSS doesn't care about the `for` attribute, it cares about `id`, `class`, and the hierarchy of the elements.

You haven't mentioned what it is you want to accomplish exatly, but give this a shot:

**HTML**

```
<label for="email">Confirm Email<input type="text" id="email" /></label>
<label for="firstname">First Name<input type="text" id="firstname" /></label>
<label for="lastname">Last Name<input type="text" id="lastname" /></label>
<label for="company">Company<input type="text" id="company" /></label>
```

**CSS**

```
label:hover { /* something */ }
```

Wrap the "label" text in a `<span>` tag if you need to.

Comment: You may need `label:hover input {/* something */}` to prevent the input inheriting properties of the label

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps

```
<div class="nina">
    <label for="email" id="em">Confirm Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" onmouseover="document.getElementById('em').style.color='red'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('em').style.color='black'" />
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" />
    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" />
    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <input type="text" id="company" />

</div>
```

this without jquery

Comment: Without jQuery... but people stopped writing js code in HTML 10 years ago

Comment: The question did not ask for a JavaScript solution. There are other non-JS alternatives