# Selecting a label placed before an input in various states

Tags: html, css

Inputs have states like `:focus` and `:valid`, and I want to paint the label for that input to reflect that. The problem is that my input form needs to look like this:

```
Field title
[input]

Field title
[input]
...
```

and there seems to be no way to select the field title based on input states. The `+` and `~` selectors only work on elements following the target. I can't reverse the order of the elements in a `direction: rtl` block either since I need the fields to be below the title.

All that's left seems to be hardcore options like `position: absolute` and to place them manually. I say hardcore since the field title have a variable height and that's a lot of manual offset typing. Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Can you post the relevant html to make the question clear? From what can see you have label first input second, and you are strict with the structure.

Comment: Related: [Is there a “previous sibling” CSS selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1817792/2065702)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and change the order of the elements using the flex `order`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /** vertical layout **/
}

.textInput {
  order: 1;
}

.field {
  order: 0;
}

.textInput:focus + .field {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="textInput">
  <label class="field">Field</label>
</div>
```